# ChartJs works with Sharepoint 2016 but not sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a chart with ChartJS and I imported the data dynamically from an xml link (odata), it worked with Sharepoint 2016 but the chart doesn't show in Sharepoint 2013. Do you have any solution for this?
This is the code:
https://codeshare.io/5gd8k8

I will appreciate it.

Note: I tried to display chartJs with static data and it worked, it didn't work with dynamic data and I'm sure that my code is fine because I copied and pasted it.

Comment: What about this? [Using Chart.js in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ideamovers/using-chart-js-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: @CaldeiraG It checked and it didn't help, it's like it's not reading data.value.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I fixed the problem.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Sharepoint 2013 doesn't accept nometadata , Here is the new code:
https://codeshare.io/5zeljW